# Multisite website configure Domain issue

Tags: multisite, htaccess

I have multi site website lets say example.com example.com/ab and example.com/cd.

Now I need to add another website in this network which is run on separate domain. lets say mywebsite.com and mydemowebsite.com

Now I have to add in existing network but must be run on main domain mywebsite.com and mydemowebsite.com

Please suggest solution.

Comment: So you're trying to mix subdomain and subdirectory multisite? [Things have changed since I last looked at this](https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-multisite-domain-mapping/) so this might now just be supported, but worst case you just need a version of sunrise.php that will resolve the site IDs correctly - the plugin linked there may still be useful - even if you have to hard-code that yourself.

Comment: yes looking for mixup

Answer (score 0):

As per the instructions for setting up WordPress MU Domain Mapping, sunrise.php needs to be placed directly in your /wp-content directory. It's not a plugin in the traditional sense, so can't be placed in mu-plugins (or even plugins for that matter).

Setting up this plugin can take a bit of manual work so take care to follow the instructions carefully, including the modifications you need to make to wp-config.php.